# Compiling 32 bit binaries on Travis with Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, travis-ci

I am trying to compile a 32 bit binary on Travis. Compilation seems to work correctly, but `-m32` does not seem to compile in 32 bit mode, as linking is not done rightly.

Instruction for compilation:

```
gcc -m32 -DUNIX -DPD -I "/usr/include/pd"  -fpic -DVERSION='"1.4.1"' \
  -I"src/uthash/src" -std=c99  -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Winline \
  -Wstrict-aliasing -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer \
  -march=pentium4 -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 \ 
  -o src/json-encode.o -c src/json-encode.c
```

Instruction for linking:

```
gcc -m32 -rdynamic -shared -fpic \ 
  -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN",--enable-new-dtags  -L "/usr/libx32" \ 
  -L "/libx32"  -o json-encode.pd_linux src/json-encode.o  -lc \ 
  -lm -lcurl -ljson-c -loauth
```

But it looks like compilation was not done in 32 bit mode, because of the messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/libx32/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/libx32/libc.a when searching for -lc
```

Before compiling, the environment is set up with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install puredata-dev libjson-c-dev libcurl4-nss-dev liboauth-dev \
  puredata-core:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libcurl3-nss:i386 liboauth0:i386 \
  libc6-dev-i386 gcc-multilib
```

Am I missing packages or gcc options?

The full log can be found at https://travis-ci.org/residuum/PuRestJson/jobs/179125198

Comment: For now I have resorted to `debootstrap` and `chroot` :-/

Answer (score 4):

`/libx32` and `/usr/libx32` are for the (legendary but niche) [x32 platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) which is *different* to i386. In short you almost certainly didn't want to include these directories in your linker search path.